# Sublime 2 Snippet XML error

Tags: xml, time, header, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm actually doing a snippet for creating headers with your name, email ...
And I would like to add the time and the date when the project start and when the last save was done.

I tryed to include :

```
<xs:element name="startdate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

With

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
<xs:restriction base="xs:anySimpleType">
<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" fixed="true"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But Sublime Text 2 returns me : "Unrecognised plis element xs:restriction"

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:simpleType name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:anySimpleType">
   <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" fixed="true"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Globals</string>
   <key>scope</key>
   <string></string>
   <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>shellVariables</key>
    <array>
     <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_TIME</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string><xs:element name="startdate" type="xs:dateTime"/></string>
     </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>0ef292cd-943a-4fb0-b43d-65959c5e6b06</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I took the

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
```

here : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch16_01.htm#ch16-77031

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?